# Definition of an almost complex hyperplane in the projective space $\mathbb{C} P^n$.

Tags: complex-geometry, projective-space, almost-complex

Let J be an almost complex Structure in the projective space $\mathbb{C} P^2$.
According to Duval a J-line in the almost complex projective space $\mathbb{C} P^2,$ is the almost complex analogue of a projective line, hence it is a J-holomorphic curve plunged in ($\mathbb{C} P^2, J$), diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C} P^1$ and of degree 1 in homology.

What is the analogue definition of a J-hyperplane in the almost complex projective space $(\mathbb{C} P^n, J)$?  ~~where J be an almost complex Structure on $\mathbb{C} P^n$.

Comment: In direct analogy, it should be a $J$-holomorphic map $u : \mathbb{CP}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ where $\mathbb{CP}^{n-1}$ is equipped with its standard complex structure.